# SQL IN Operator with an exact match?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN ('Paris','London');
```

How would I change it to match exact case (basically exact match)? i.e. `lOnDoN` would not be included in the results.

Answer (score 7):

[Use `BINARY` to force a binary (byte for byte) string comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE BINARY City IN ('Paris','London');
```

Or, if you always want the `City` column to be case sensitive, consider [altering the collation of the column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: This does not work in IBM DB2

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if `BINARY` would work with `IN`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE BINARY City IN ('Paris','London')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BINARY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE BINARY City IN ('Paris','London')
```

BINARY Work like below.

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'A';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'A';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'a ';
        -> 0
```

Please find more info on [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary)